# Display the modified list using a java.util.Iterator<E> object and a while loop

Tags: java, iterator, abstract

A) Define the following method in MyList and implement it in MyAbstractList.

```
// Adds the elements in otherList to this list.
// Returns true if
// this list changed as a result of the call.
public boolean addAll(MyList<E> otherlist)
```

B) Add code to “TestMyArrayList.java” to demonstrate that this method works correctly.

**Display the modified list using a java.util.Iterator object and a while loop.**

OK so I've already finished the Part A and I'm confused on part B. I don't understand what my professor wants me to do. I've done some stuff in it but I'm pretty sure it's not correct. Anybody knows if I'm even doing it correctly?

This is my MyList class

```
package listapi;

/**
 * @author Y. Daniel Liang
 */
public interface MyList<E> extends java.lang.Iterable<E> {

/** Add a new element at the end of this list*/
public void add(E e);

/**Add a new element at the specified index in this list*/
public void add(int index, E e);

/**Clear the list*/
public void clear();

/**Return true if this list contains the element*/
public boolean contains(E e);

/**Return the element from this list at the specified index*/
public E get(int index);

/**Return the index of the first matching element in this list. Return -1 if
 * no match.*/
public int indexOf(E e);

/**Return true if this list contains no elements*/
public boolean isEmpty();

/**Return the index of the last matching element in this list Return -1 if
 * no match.*/
public int lastIndexOf(E e);

/**Remove the first occurrence of the element o from this list. Shift any
 * subsequent elements to the left. Return true if the element is removed.*/
public boolean remove(E e);

/**Remove the element at the specified position in this list Shift any
 * subsequent elements to the left. Return the element that was removed from
 * the list.*/
public E remove(int index);

/**Replace the element at the specified position in this list with the
 * specified element and returns the new set.*/
public Object set(int index, E e);

/** Return the number of elements in this list */
public int size();

public boolean addAll(MyList<E> otherList);
}
```

This is my MyAbstractList class

```
package listapi;

/**
 * @author Y. Daniel Liang
 */
public abstract class MyAbstractList<E> implements MyList<E> {

protected int size = 0; // The size of the list

/**
 * Create a default list
 */
protected MyAbstractList() {
}

/**
 * Create a list from an array of objects
 */
protected MyAbstractList(E[] objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        add(objects[i]);
    }
}

@Override
/**
 * Add a new element at the end of this list
 */
public void add(E e) {
    add(size, e);
}

@Override
/**
 * Return true if this list contains no elements
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

@Override
/**
 * Return the number of elements in this list
 */
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
/**
 * Remove the first occurrence of the element e from this list. Shift any
 * subsequent elements to the left. Return true if the element is removed.
 */
public boolean remove(E e) {
    if (indexOf(e) >= 0) {
        remove(indexOf(e));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean addAll(MyList<E> otherList) {
    for (E e : otherList) {
        add(e);
    }
    if (otherList.size() > 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}


}
```

This is where I need to add code to demonstrate that my addAll method is working correctly by displaying modified list using java.lang.iterator and a while loop

```
package listapi;

/**
 * @author Y. Daniel Liang
 */
public class TestMyArrayList {

public TestMyArrayList() {
    // Create a list
    MyList<String> list = new MyArrayList<>();

    // Add elements to the list
    list.add("America"); // Add it to the list
    System.out.println("(1) " + list);

    list.add(0, "Canada"); // Add it to the beginning of the list
    System.out.println("(2) " + list);

    list.add("Russia"); // Add it to the end of the list
    System.out.println("(3) " + list);

    list.add("France"); // Add it to the end of the list
    System.out.println("(4) " + list);

    list.add(2, "Germany"); // Add it to the list at index 2
    System.out.println("(5) " + list);

    list.add(5, "Norway"); // Add it to the list at index 5
    System.out.println("(6) " + list);

    // Remove elements from the list
    list.remove("Canada"); // Same as list.remove(0) in this case
    System.out.println("(7) " + list);

    list.remove(2); // Remove the element at index 2
    System.out.println("(8) " + list);

    list.remove(list.size() - 1); // Remove the last element
    System.out.print("(9) " + list + "\n(10) ");

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.print(s.toUpperCase() + " ");
    }
Iterator itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Object a = itr.next();
        System.out.println(a);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new MyArrayList();

}
```

}

Comment: Create a second list, use 'addAll' to add the existing 'list', and print out the new list.